# Why am I getting EXC_BREAKPOINT while iterating through every node in the scene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

The following function gets called when a user clicks a button.

```
func wipeScreen() {
    removeGestureRecognizers()
    scene?.children.forEach({ (node) in
        node.children.forEach({ (childOfNode) in
            childOfNode.removeFromParent()
        })
        node.removeFromParent()
    })
}
```

It works as intended unless it is pressed extremely fast (few times a second)

When I do this button mashing to reproduce the bug, I get the infamous:

> > Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x106667814)

Specifically on line reading `scene?.children.forEach({ (node) in`

If anyone has an idea what I can do to solve this problem it would be very  appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It can be the case that in your first foreach statement node.children is nil and calling foreach on it causes the exception. Try putting that code in if statement and check to see if it is nil or not.